# Can't access canvas element in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, canvas, html5-canvas

I got a iframe and I want to select a canvas element in this iframe. But it doesn't work. I'm using the following code.

This is my iframe

```
<body>
  <div id="canvasdiv" width="300" height="300"></div>
</body>
```

This is my parent page

```
<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" frameborder="0" width="325" height="325" src="..."></iframe>
```

With javascript I add a canvas with some properties. For example the id.

```
canvas.node.id = "canvas";
```

In my parent page I got the following javascript.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
alert(iframe);
var iframe_canvas = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
alert(iframe_canvas);
var canvas = iframe_canvas.getElementById("canvas");
alert(canvas);
```

Result:

```
iframe = iframe element
iframe_canvas = html element
canvas = null
```

Does somebody know why I can't access the canvas element? =(

Comment: you're using the id "canvas" in the JavaScript but "canvasdiv" in the HTML ...

Comment: Code you provide doesn't contain any `iframe` element. Does your `<canvas>` element has `canvas` id? Also you have unnecessary space mark here  `iframe_canvas .get`

Comment: Is the .src of your iframe on the same domain as the host page?  If not, same-origin security policies will prevent access to the iframe contents from the parent page.

Comment: Yes, they got the same host page. and the `iframe_canvas .get` is just a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: It's hard to help when you give us such little snippets of code.  For example, if `canvas` is the DOM object, why use `canvas.node.id` rather than `canvas.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I solved the problem. Thanks for all the replies. =)

To test the getElementById function I called it by `$(document).ready`. But at this time the iframe wasn't rendered by the browser. That's why I could access the iframe it self but not the elements of the iframe. Now I assigned the function to a button and it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to your HTML, this line of code:

```
var canvas = iframe_canvas.getElementById("canvas");
```

should be this to target the proper id value in your div:

```
var canvas = iframe_canvas.getElementById("canvasdiv");
```

Comment: Ok, I changed it to 'iframe_canvas.getElementById("canvasdiv");'. But the value is still 'null'.

Comment: I think we'd have to see a live version of the page to diagnose further or see your entire code and HTML, not just the snippets you've disclosed.  There's nothing wrong with the snippets so the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're omitting the code that adds the `<canvas>` element itself. Are you sure its `id` is `canvas`?

If you are, then you might be running into same-origin policy problems regarding accessing contents of iframes.

Comment: I completed my code. As you can see, the id of the canvas is canvas. =)

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine expect for one part. 
replace 
    `getElementById("canvas")`
with
     `getElementById("canvasdiv");`